# Highcharts - Stack Graph Display Average of all values

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts for statistical data displaying.  I want to display , on the stack label , the average of all the values .

Below is what i am doing but i cant seem to get it right :

```
yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Task'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {

                        return (this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x]).toPrecision(2) + '%';

                    }
                }
        },
```

The above only takes the last value on the stack and shows the percentage. For instance , if the last value is 50 , the above displays 50% as the stack value . I want to take an average of all the values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Average of all the values of that particular column or average of All values of complete chart ?

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi average of the all the column values of course

Comment: Let's analyse that kind of chart: http://jsfiddle.net/40evxyhd/ which prints average as line. The value of this line should be printed in stacklabel (above each column) or Im wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show any stack's percentage mean if your stacked column has two stack A-5 and B-10 , then the % of B in column is 66% and % of A is 33%. If you want to show that use following in formatter function ( refer [This Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/prJjY/303/))

```
 formatter: function() {

                    return (this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x] / this.total * 100).toPrecision(2) + '%';

                }
```

**Updating as per OP 's comment** [Refer Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/prJjY/300/)

Use following code : Make your data in a variable and calculate the sum

```
var seriesData =  [{
            name: 'Incomplete',
            data: [1, 3, 4, 7, 20]
        }, {
            name: 'Complete',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }];
  var total = 0;
   $.each(seriesData,function(item){
    $.each(seriesData[item].data,function() {
     total += this;

  }); 
});
```

And then use following in stacklabel formatter :

```
       formatter: function() {

                    return ( this.total/ total * 100).toPrecision(2) + '%';

                } 


    series:seriesData
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Even though the fiddle shows the output , i am not able to get it correctly

Comment: @user1411837 please see updated answer as per your comment and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/prJjY/300/

Comment: here the total value is showing wrong . It should show only the total value for every column and not the whole graph

Comment: So my question is: If a column has two stack one is 5 another is 10.. then what should be the stacklabel ? 5+10 =15 * percent of what? first value's % or second value's %?

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi the poster is looking for the average - so in your scenario, the label would be 7.5

Comment: I posted that solution in starting, but poster wanted what I updated  latest

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be as easy as it should be.

I would accomplish this by pre-processing the data to generate an array of averages, and then referencing that array from the stackLabels formatter function.

Example, build the averages (assumes array 'data' with sub array for each series data values):

```
var sum = 0;
var averages = [];
var dataLen = data.length;
$.each(data[0], function(x, point) {
    sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
    sum += data[i][x];
  }
  averages.push(sum/dataLen);
})
```

And then in the formatter:

```
yAxis : { 
  stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(averages[this.x],2);
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/vatdrecb/

If I could find a way to get a reliable count of the points in each stack, you could just use

`return this.total/countOfPoints;`

in the formatter without needing to build an array, but I can't seem to reliably get that count.