# How to ignore zero when getting average for stacked bar chart datalabels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztw9B.png)

My chart is hiding  hiding zeros.

I want to calculate the average for the stacked datalabels but its counting the 0.

yAxis.StackLabels.formatter = "function() {return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total /this.axis.chart.series.length);}"

this.axis.chart.series.length gives me 3 when it should be 2 if one of them is 0.

"function() { return this.axis.series[0].yData[this.x];}"

Result: 42,0,0,0,0,57

Comment: Would need to know how the numeric value that you want to filter out is stored in a single `series`. You could `console.log` out one and post is here. After that we can filter the `series` to exclude `0` values.

Comment: @vdot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35459718/12171673) is possible solution. I'm still working on mapping the series and dividing it by `series.options.data.length`, at this case series you can get from `this.axis.series`.